# Pushing Fortio in cloud foundry using docker image

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to push Fortio(a load testing tool for microservices) as an application in cloud foundry. I am trying it with a docker image from hub.

```
   cf push <app-name> --docker-image fortio:fortio random-route
```

Application crashes when it tries to start the application. cf logs says : executable file not found in $PATH

It is working fine in my local docker setup but not in cloud foundry.

Any help??

Comment: Please remove tags which are not related to your question

Comment: Are you specifying `cf push -c` or are you relying on the CMD or ENTRYPOINT set by the docker image? What are those supposed to run?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/push-docker.html

> A Docker image that meets the following requirements:
>   The Docker image must contain an /etc/passwd file with an entry for the root user. In addition, the home directory and the shell for that root user must be present in the image file system.

Unfortunately, public Docker image `fortio/fortio` doesn't meet this particular requirement.

Solutions:

- build customized Docker app image with shell and `/etc/passwd`
- use source code and push it as a native golang app and not a Dockerized app